# How to fetch data before component mount in Svelte?

Tags: events, components, lifecycle, mount, svelte-3

Unlike `onMount` there is no `beforeMount` lifecycle event in SvelteJS. So, how do we fetch data that the page depends on before mounting? `onMount` fetches produces glitches. One can say that I can wrap dependent DOM inside if conditions. But I don't think it is the right solution. Very like in Sapper there is a `preload` function that can load page dependent data before mounting. What is the alternative to this (Sapper's `preload`) behavior in SvelteJS?

Answer (score 4):

You'd create another component that doesn't render the Component until the data is ready.

```html
<script>
import Post from "./Post.svelte";

const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
const promise = fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
</script>

{#await promise then data}
    <Post title={data.title} />
{/await}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/940c08d6657f4f3289bfd4444440a1ac?version=3.24.1)

Depending on the scenario you can use a router that has data loading supports, like the [sveltekit](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#loading) router.

Comment: Does this work with svelte-kit?

Comment: This only seems to work if I refresh the page, not between route changes.

Comment: In sveltekit you're got export const load

Answer (score 3):

You can put the `fetch` code right under `<script>` tag

> A `<script>` block contains JavaScript that runs when a component instance is created.

There is also `context="module"` attribute with `<script>` tag. It

> runs once when the module first evaluates, rather than for each component instance

See [the official docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#script)

Comment: Glad you replied. But this can't be an alternative to Sapper's ``preload()``

Answer (score 2):

Noob here, to your sub-question: isnt svelte front end only? Meaning no SSR support and thus no option for preloading data with first user request.

Since, you dont have any server that would preload your data and give the user prepacked front-end (svelte pages) with data. Thus, you need sapper to provide a functionality where server can fetch data with first user request, populate front end and send it to user.. This way, user receives svelte pages, populated with data, upon first response from your server.

Since you use only svelte, user needs to contact your server more often.. First, it fetches the front-end, then front-end fetches data from back-end. Furthermore, it aint SEO friendly as robots dont wait for the subsequent server responses. Thus, your pages wont be analyzed properly as robots analyze 'blank'page, no data mounted yet, and move to next, before response can be processed.

Please, correct me If I am wrong ;)

I believe above answer is right: 
 1. create empty variable in script tag
 2. add below onMount call and fetch data from serverto above declared variable
 3. check if var is empty and show loading button
 4. if var isnt empty, then show user content
 6. profit?

P.S: Sorry for any misconceptions or bad English :)